# Cannot set disabled opacity on TouchableOpacity

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to add functionality to disable functionality to a button. I want the button to be non-clickable and have lower opacity. When I click the button, I set the state in my outer component that the button should be disabled (this is while waiting for response from a server). The non-clickable part works, but I cannot get it to lower its opacity after it has been clicked.

**Component**

```
<MyButton onPress={ this.setWaiting.bind(this) }
          disabled={ this.state.waiting } />
```

**MyButton**

```
const disabledStyle = {
    opacity: 0.2,
}

....

<TouchableOpacity
    style={ [styles.button, props.disabled && disabledStyle] }
    onPress={ onPress }
    disabled={ props.disabled }>
        ....
</TouchableOpacity>
```

If I change `disabledStyle` to set another background color though, it works as expected and changes the background color while `disabled` is true.

Comment: If it's not too inconvenient you could use `{[ styles.button, { opacity: props.disabled ? 0.2 : 1 }]}`. Change `1` to be your desired opacity when the button is not disabled.

Comment: @Dan that still does not work and gives the same result as before.

Comment: Can you verify that `this.state.waiting` is in fact modifying the props of MyButton? Here's a quick example with the styles mentioned in the first comment - https://snack.expo.io/ry79Yn43b

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it runs. It works as expected for me also when I set it to always be disabled. The problem appears when I use the state variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may not be using the best component for what you're trying to do. [TouchableOpacity](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.49/docs/touchableopacity.html#touchableopacity) appears to be a helper component meant to dim the children on press.

You could try the [documented setOpacityTo() method](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.49/docs/touchableopacity.html#setopacityto) and see if that gets you where you want to go, but I think what you really want is [TouchableHighlight](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.49/docs/touchablehighlight.html)